# Part of the Total Coloring Conjecture Proof

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

While the Total Coloring Conjecture has not yet been proven, there are a couple proofs relating to it that are trivial according to Open Problem Garden. Proving that the lower bound for the chromatic color is $ \Delta(G)+1 $ makes sense in that each edge connected to the vertex is a different color (so $ \Delta(G) $ colors) and the vertex itself is another color (plus $ 1 $ color), but I cannot seem to wrap my head around $ \chi''(G)\leq 2\Delta(G)+2 $.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/behzads_conjecture

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that $\chi''(G) \le \chi(G) + \chi'(G)$: we can get a total coloring of $G$ by using $\chi(G)$ colors on the vertices and $\chi'(G)$ separate colors on the edges.

We have $\chi(G) \le \Delta(G)+1$ by a greedy coloring: if you color the vertices one at a time, and you have $\Delta(G)+1$ colors, then no vertex has more than $\Delta(G)$ options eliminated when you get to it, so you can still color it.

We have $\chi'(G) \le \Delta(G)+1$ by [Vizing's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing's_theorem).

Comment: +1. I am not sure but seemingly the total coloring conjecture has been resolved! [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09658)

Comment: @C.F.G The paper looks very technical, so it's hard to verify, but I think a strike against it is the following paper by the same author using the same approach: [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.10240). That would be a 17-page proof of a much more famous open problem and in particular a short proof of the 4-color theorem - if correct. My completely *nonmathematical* assessment is that this is "too much of a good thing" and that surely the polynomial method has been tried many times on the 4-color theorem and is not enough; it is more likely that some misunderstanding is at work, instead.

Comment: You meant you think the proof is probably incorrect?

Comment: Yes, that's my feeling based on approximately 10 minutes of looking; you should feel free to draw your own conclusions.

Comment: But it has been posted in 2020 and it is still there!! the proof seems is the result of a 4-year research program and grant. It is hard to me to say that it is incorrect (but I like open problems to remain open!)

Comment: Nothing gets deleted from arXiv (well, maybe in the case of blatant plagiarism or something like that - I don't know - but certainly not in the case of an incorrect proof), so whether it's there or not is zero evidence. I think that unless I come to a point in my life where I have to bet on the total coloring conjecture being true or false, I will wait to see if this paper is published in a peer-reviewed journal or not.